# Use a different Navigation once logged in

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2

I'm trying to change the login menu in Cordova / Ionic 2 once the user has logged in. For example, the user should only see a link to edit his or hers account once logged in, but once they log out they should not be able to view any form of account information.

Within `app.component.ts` I've setup a secondary navigation menu:

```
  this.loggedInNav = [,
      { title: 'Account Information', component: account_informationPage, icon: "arrow-dropright" },
      { title: 'Settings', component: settingsPage, icon: "settings" },
      { title: 'Contact', component: contactPage, icon: "contact" }
  ];
```

But i have no idea how to use this menu. Is there anyway I could call a variable in this class from another page? If so, that could mean I could setup a simple boolean expression stating if the user has logged in, then within the template implementation use `this.loggedInNav` and loop through that.

I've looked through the Ionic documentation for some further information but I've been unable to find anything.

-- Edit --

This is the template file implementation:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        <ion-icon name="{{p.icon}}" [ngStyle]="{'padding-right': '20px', 'min-width': '40px', 'margin': '0 auto', 'font-size': '30px'}" item-start></ion-icon>
        {{p.title}}
</button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>
```

Like I said, it would be really good if I could have something like `ng-if=loggedIn == true` where `loggedIn` could be called from another page, somehow...

Comment: how are you setting the default menu?

Comment: I'll update the question to show what is in the template file.

Comment: `loggedIn could be called from another page` what do you mean? set the variable in logout page?

Comment: I think the easiest way is to have a distinct sub-route. like `anyonymous/...` and redirect in a route guard if not authenticated. If  you don't want that, you can update the routes at runtime.

Comment: If I could have a variable within `app.component.ts` called:

`loggedIn: boolean`, then lets say I have a page called `authorised-user`, and in that page I could set `loggedIn` to true, which then tells the template file to use the `loggedInNav` defined in my original question.

There may be another way to do this (the proper way), but I've been unable to find anything after a week of googling.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean @GünterZöchbauer ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the full question. If you just show/hide some UI elements, you can use a shared service that provides the login state, then you can inject the service where you need to know the state and use `*ngIf` to show/hide elements just like you asked for in the last paragraph of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Events`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) API for publishing/subscribing the login event.
You can subscribe to the event in multiple pages and add functions that need to be executed on its occurrence.

In your login page,

```
//inject events from ionic-angular
constructor(private events:Events){}

login(){
   //publish the login event event
   this.events.publish('user:loggedin');
   //other login related stuff
}
logout(){
   this.events.publish('user:loggedout');
}
```

In your app component page ts,

```
//inject events from ionic-angular
constructor(private events:Events){}

ngOnInit(){
   this.events.subscribe('user:loggedin',()=>{this.loggedIn=true});
   this.events.subscribe('user:loggedout',()=>{this.loggedIn=false});
}
```

In your HTML, use `*ngIf` to set your menu list.

Comment: This looks more like it! I didn't realise there was the method for publishing/subscribing events. This looks a lot more robust. Thanks

Comment: glad it helped you out:)

Comment: I'll get this up and running and then either accept the answer or post a question!

Comment: So I'm able to send events around my code now which is great, but `app.component` where the navigation menu is built only ever gets initialised once, this causes a big problem - meaning I can't change what items to show in my side bar.

Comment: can you add how you are setting the menu?

Comment: I'm using the default Ionic-Sidemenu template. The app root is set to the `app.component.ts` file, and the html template has been shown in my original post.

Comment: just reset `pages` to the new set in the login event subscribe..instead of `*ngIf`

Comment: I don't understand... The `app.component.ts` is only ever called once, how can I refresh that page without refreshing the whole entire app?

Comment: angular's change detection should detect the change in the `pages` variable and update the view.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/GX7R427N I think I understand what you're saying but angular updating my view isn't the issue here. I need to, in a way, re-initialise the content in `app.component.ts`

Comment: you dont seem to have injected events in app.component.ts and subscribed to it..See the last part of my answer

Comment: Ah I see! So the subscription kind of acts like an event of sorts. I've got it functioning now, thank you.